# telerik - add toolbar and command to an existing kendo UI grid

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid

I have this grid

```
$("#LocationGrid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: locationDataSource,
editable: "inline",
columns: [  { field: "LocationID", hidden: "hidden" },
            { field: "LocationName", title: "Location Name" },
            { command: [{ name: "edit" }] }]
});
```

i want to add toolbar with create button to this grid if the user has permission

```
if(condition) //user has permission
{
 //add toolbar to grid
 toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add New Location}],
}
```

and also add "Delete" button to command column if the user has permission

```
if(condition) //user has permission
{
 //add delete button to grid
 command: [{ name: "delete"}]
}
```

how i can perform this, please?

Comment: Hi. Did you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `setOptions()` method of grid like below,

```
if(condition)
{
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
  grid.setOptions({
    toolbar: [{name: "create", text: "Add New Location"}]
  });
}
```

Refer http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setOptions